# Cannot Compile Kernel Headers (libc6-amd64 Dependencies)

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel

Edit: Please read the update.

I was unable to compile some programs using boost libraries and I was told it was a compiler error. I compiled GCC-5.1.0 from source and placed it in `/opt/gcc-5.1.0/` as well as added `/opt/gcc-5.1.0/bin` to `$PATH`. I also had to downgrade from kernel 4.3.0 to 4.2.6 for VMWare workstation to properly work.

I am unable to install my kernel headers produced by a kernel compilation script I wrote:
`dpkg -i /kernel/Kernel4.2.6/linux-headers-4.2.6.deb`

Output:

```
Unpacking linux-headers-4.2.6 (1.0.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-4.2.6:
 linux-headers-4.2.6 depends on libc6-amd64 (>= 2.14).
```

That being said, running `dpkg -l "libc6*"` yields the following:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  libc6:amd64    2.19-18+deb8 amd64        GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6:i386     2.19-18+deb8 i386         GNU C Library: Shared libraries
rc  libc6-amd64    2.19-18+deb8 i386         GNU C Library: 64bit Shared libra
ii  libc6-dev:amd6 2.19-18+deb8 amd64        GNU C Library: Development Librar
ii  libc6-dev:i386 2.19-18+deb8 i386         GNU C Library: Development Librar
in  libc6-dev-amd6 <none>       i386         (no description available)
ii  libc6-dev-i386 2.19-18+deb8 amd64        GNU C Library: 32-bit development
ii  libc6-i386     2.19-18+deb8 amd64        GNU C Library: 32-bit shared libr
ii  libc6-i686:i38 2.19-18+deb8 i386         GNU C Library: Shared libraries [
rc  libc6-x32      2.19-18+deb8 amd64        GNU C Library: X32 ABI Shared lib
un  libc6.1        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  libc6.1-dev    <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

The dependencies seem to meet the requirements, do they not?

I am unable to run `apt-get install libc6-dev-amd64` because it yields:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-amd64_2.19-18+deb8u1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/sys/xattr.h', which is also in package libc6-dev-i386 2.19-18+deb8u1
```

However, running `dpkg --force-overwrite -d /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-amd64_2.19-18+deb8u1_i386.deb` from the cache seems to have installed it. `dpkg -l "libc6*"` now yields:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  libc6:amd64    2.19-18+deb8 amd64        GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6:i386     2.19-18+deb8 i386         GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6-amd64    2.19-18+deb8 i386         GNU C Library: 64bit Shared libra
ii  libc6-dev:amd6 2.19-18+deb8 amd64        GNU C Library: Development Librar
ii  libc6-dev:i386 2.19-18+deb8 i386         GNU C Library: Development Librar
ii  libc6-dev-amd6 2.19-18+deb8 i386         GNU C Library: 64bit Development 
ii  libc6-dev-i386 2.19-18+deb8 amd64        GNU C Library: 32-bit development
ii  libc6-i386     2.19-18+deb8 amd64        GNU C Library: 32-bit shared libr
ii  libc6-i686:i38 2.19-18+deb8 i386         GNU C Library: Shared libraries [
ii  libc6-udeb     2.19-0ubuntu amd64        Embedded GNU C Library: Shared li
rc  libc6-x32      2.19-18+deb8 amd64        GNU C Library: X32 ABI Shared lib
un  libc6.1        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  libc6.1-dev    <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

However, I am still unable to install the kernel headers with the same error.

As a plausibly related issue, after compiling a very simple program checking for dependencies:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <linux/limits.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    return 0;
}
```

It seems to compile correctly, but running `./a.out` yields:

```
./a.out: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./a.out)
./a.out: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by ./a.out)
```

**Update:**
Nothing seems to have worked. I've tried installing experimental versions of `libc6-dev` and other eglib libraries, and now I am unable to uninstall, change, or do anything to them, lest I be met with the removal of the following packages:

```
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  apt libapt-pkg4.12 (due to apt) libc6 (due to apt) libgcc1 (due to apt)
  libstdc++6 (due to apt) debian-archive-keyring (due to apt) gnupg (due to
  apt) base-files base-passwd libdebconfclient0 (due to base-passwd) bash
  debianutils (due to bash) dash (due to bash) libncurses5 (due to bash)
  libtinfo5 (due to bash) bsdutils libsystemd0 (due to bsdutils) coreutils
  libacl1 (due to coreutils) libattr1 (due to coreutils) libselinux1 (due to
  coreutils) dpkg (due to dash) diffutils libbz2-1.0 (due to dpkg) liblzma5
  (due to dpkg) zlib1g (due to dpkg) tar (due to dpkg) e2fsprogs e2fslibs (due
  to e2fsprogs) libblkid1 (due to e2fsprogs) libcomerr2 (due to e2fsprogs)
  libss2 (due to e2fsprogs) libuuid1 (due to e2fsprogs) util-linux (due to
  e2fsprogs) findutils grep libpcre3 (due to grep) gzip hostname init
  systemd-sysv (due to init) libc-bin login libaudit1 (due to login) libpam0g
  (due to login) libpam-runtime (due to login) libpam-modules (due to login)
  mount libmount1 (due to mount) libsmartcols1 (due to mount) ncurses-bin
  perl-base sed sysvinit-utils startpar (due to sysvinit-utils) initscripts
  (due to util-linux) tzdata (due to util-linux) libslang2 (due to util-linux)
```

Clearly I don't want to uninstall these, but I need to re-isntall libc6.

Answer (score 1):

---

If you compiled your application with g++ version 5.1.0, the compiler will know the path to it's own `libstdc++.so` . ( In /opt/ ).

But your application ( a.out ) will look for `libstdc++.so.6` in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

You can run a.out like `$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/gcc-5.1.0/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && ./a.out`

---

Comment: Taking that advice, I moved the libstdc++.so.6.0.21 (old version was ...0.20) and changed the symlink to point to it. That is solved. However, I still am now unable to compile with -m32. I receive an error `cannot find crt1.o, crti.o, -lc, crtn.o`

Comment: For relevance: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/gcc-5.1.0/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib32:/usr/lib64:/opt/gcc-5.1.0/lib:/opt/gcc-5.1.0/lib`

Answer (score 0):

---

About your missing { crt1.o, crti.o, -lc = libc.so, crtn.o } : Those are  32bits files required for compiling with `gcc -m32`

→ → http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compile-32bit-application-using-gcc-64-bit-linux.html

→ `$ sudo apt-get install g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386`

---

Comment: Why don't you join those two answers into one and then get rid of another?